# Sobrepor a seta para voltar ao topo sobre videos, imagens, etc

Tags: javascript, css

Não estou conseguindo sobrepor a seta para voltar ao top que é fixa [em minha página](https://www.guiago.net).

Sempre quando passa por imagens, videos e algumas aplicações que usam JavaScript ela some.

Gostaria de saber se há alguma solução especifica.

Uso os seguintes código para uso da seta

```
<a class="botaotopo scroll" href="#banner" title="Para o topo !">
    <img src="images/to-top.png" border="0" />
</a>
```

E o CSS da classe o outro é :

```
.botaotopo {
  display:scroll;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:2px;
  right:2px;
}
```

E o JS:

```
(function($){$.fn.UItoTop=function(options){var defaults={text:'To Top',min:200,inDelay:600,outDelay:400,containerID:'toTop',containerHoverID:'toTopHover',scrollSpeed:1200,easingType:'linear'},settings=$.extend(defaults,options),containerIDhash='#'+settings.containerID,containerHoverIDHash='#'+settings.containerHoverID;$('body').append('<a href="#" id="'+settings.containerID+'">'+settings.text+'</a>');$(containerIDhash).hide().on('click.UItoTop',function(){$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0},settings.scrollSpeed,settings.easingType);$('#'+settings.containerHoverID,this).stop().animate({'opacity':0},settings.inDelay,settings.easingType);return false;}).prepend('<span id="'+settings.containerHoverID+'"></span>').hover(function(){$(containerHoverIDHash,this).stop().animate({'opacity':1},600,'linear');},function(){$(containerHoverIDHash,this).stop().animate({'opacity':0},700,'linear');});$(window).scroll(function(){var sd=$(window).scrollTop();if(typeof document.body.style.maxHeight==="undefined"){$(containerIDhash).css({'position':'absolute','top':sd+$(window).height()-50});}
if(sd>settings.min)
$(containerIDhash).fadeIn(settings.inDelay);else
$(containerIDhash).fadeOut(settings.Outdelay);});};})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elementos com um z-index maior são empilhados diante dos elementos com um menor z-index

```
 .botaotopo {
   z-index: 1;
   ..........
   ..........
```

> No seu caso isso vai funcionar, só vai parecer que não lá no rodapé que é da mesma cor :)

Comment: Excelente resolveu meu problema, muito obrigado!